# Nuget Problems Downloading Scripts

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Ok, this has happened before, I'm not sure what the deal is.

I go to install this nuget package-
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax

the package is installed "correctly" both using the command line and the GUI.  But there is no scripts added to my project?

I had the same problem with MVC6 Grid.  At least there I could hack the scripts in.

I found the actual script on Microsoft's CDN page so I can work around this...just wondering if I'm missing something.

Using Visual Studio 2017 and the Project is a Core 2.0 MVC project if that helps.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the package is installed "correctly" both using the command line and the GUI. But there is no scripts added to my project?

Since **the usage of NuGet for css/javascript libraries is discouraged**. You should use `Bower` or the `npm` (Node Package Manager) to add the JavaScript libraries instead of using NuGet. The newer project file formats, `PackageReferences`, only supports files that are in a `contentFiles` directory inside the NuGet package.

To use the package `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` to the .net core project, you need to select your MVC project and add a new file to the project root. While in the template manager (Add->New Item...), search for "Bower Configuration File" or "npm Configuration file".

Then edit the file and add your dependency, i.e.

package.json (npm) or bower.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery-ajax-unobtrusive": "3.2.4"
  }
```

[image]

Note: For package.json (npm), once you save, the file will be downloaded in a directory named "node_modules`. This alone won't be enough, as the required files **need to be copied over to wwwroot folder**, where they can be accessed when the application runs.

For the detailed info, see [NPM, BOWER, NUGET, GULP – The Four Horsemen of ASP.NET CORE Apps](http://fiyazhasan.me/npm-bower-nuget-gulp-the-four-horsemen-of-asp-net-core-apps/).