# How to install packages to Scrip folder

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-cordova

I have my app (Tools for Apache Cordova) in Azure DevOps. I want to build the app in Azure DevOps. I added NuGet Tool Installer and NuGet restore tasks.

But NuGet restores tasks and put files in packages folder only (for example AngularJs).

In Microsoft Visual Studio I use `Update-Package -reinstall` command in Package Manager Console for put files to the "scripts" folder. and those files are had references by other ts files.

How can I rewrite command `Update-Package -reinstall` to Azure DevOps task?

I tried to add NuGet custom task with command install. It's working without error even not found packages.

UPD:

[packages and scripts have different hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtvNy.png)

Comment: Are you saying you want azure to unpack the package _lib/_ in to your project _scripts/_ directory?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. I want to do like it do Update-Package -reinstall command in Package Manager Console. Because packages folder have sub folder with version in name. So I can't properly make reference in my type script files. Opposite  in scripts folder I have right hierarchy. Of course I could commit script folder in repository, but there are auto generated files so I prefered keep it auto generated during build in Azure DevOps too.

Comment: Are you using Package Reference syntax in your project, or are you using a packages.config file? Also, I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say `custom task with command install. it's working without error...` Is the custom nuget task using the install command not working as you expect?

Comment: I use packages.config. Under "custom task with command install. it's working without error..." I mean next I added NuGet task and selected custom in Command dropdown. Set "install" for Command and arguments field. And when I run build I don't get error in this task. All green. I was looking at logs and it looks like my project wasn't found.

Comment: is this a .net core or standard project? Maybe using the `dotnet build` task (which does an implicit restore on sdk 2.x) will get you the behavior you're looking for. Can you update your question with a screenshot of your build pipeline tasks?

Comment: This is Tools for Apache Cordova project. No .net at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I rewrite command Update-Package -reinstall to Azure DevOps
>   task?

First, you could not use this command line `Update-Package -reinstall` to Azure DevOps task. That because package manager console is providing is access to **visual studio objects**:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1512

So, we could not use the Package manager console powershell outside visual studio.

> How to install packages to Scrip folder

Since nuget restore task only restores files in the packages directory (\packages folder ), but does not restore files inside your project or otherwise modify your project. We have to copy those `.js` to the `/scripts` folder manually.

To resolve this issue, we could add a copy task to the Azure DevOps after nuget restore to copy those files from `/packages` folder to the `/scripts` folder. Or you could add those `.js` to the source control.

Besides, the usage of NuGet for css/javascript libraries is discouraged. You should use  the npm (Node Package Manager) to add the JavaScript libraries instead of using NuGet.

[Nuget Problems Downloading Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838394/nuget-problems-downloading-scripts)

If you are interested, please see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript?view=vsts&tabs=yaml) and [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav%2Cwindows) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean Azure DevOps doesn't support case when user use nuget for manage javascript packages?

Comment: No, nuget doesn't have an advantage when dealing with .js type packages, but you can still use it. Just like the problem you're experiencing, we need to add additional copy steps. We can use the npm task, Azure DevOps also support  npm task.

Comment: @Pavel, Besides, what you want to put files to the "scripts" folder, you should "install" the nuget package, but "install" need access to visual studio objects, otherwise, nuget could not modify the project file. This is the reason for your issue, so we could not put files to the "scripts" folder with nuget task directly on the Azure DevOps, need manually copy or add them into the source control. Hope you can understand this issue more clear. Happy a nice day.

Comment: Thank you @Leo Liu-MSFT yes, I think I understand issue more clear. I hope, task will be created in future

Comment: I decided to use workaround and I commited js files from script folder to repository. It's working now and I haven't block issue now. Thank you Leo and  Josh.

Answer (score 0):

In the NuGet task, you can press on "Advanced" and specify the folder where the packages will be downloaded there, so type there the "scripts" folder path.

[image]

Comment: This case in folder script will be hierarchy like in folder packages. So not like in repository.