# Page not rendering as expected in MVC 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm getting started with MVC after a long history with WebForms, and I've hit a wall right out of the gate.

Some background: I've started out with an empty MVC project, as I don't want my production application filled with all the fluff that comes with the full MVC project. But, to support my learning, I've added a full MVC project to the solution and copied over what I believe to be the necessary files/code for what I'm trying to accomplish.

First of all, here's what I'm after:

[image: Expected]

(This is from the tutorial found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view).)

But here's what I'm getting instead:

[image: Actual]

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47862005), the use of NuGet has been deprecated for packages like JQuery and Bootstrap. So I installed NodeJS and NPM and installed these two packages here:

[image]

I then set the project's pre-build event:

```
xcopy D:\Dev\Packages\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\*.* D:\MyApp\Styles\ /s /y
xcopy D:\Dev\Packages\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\*.*  D:\MyApp\Scripts\ /s /y
xcopy D:\Dev\Packages\node_modules\jquery\dist\*.*        D:\MyApp\Scripts\ /s /y
```

This is so only the necessary files make it into my pipeline. (There may be a better, more accepted way of doing this, but it's what I thought of at the time.)

Here's my bundle registration:

```
Imports System.Web.Optimization

Public Module BundleConfig
  Public Sub RegisterBundles(Bundles As BundleCollection)
    Bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.js"))
    Bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"))
    Bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/content/css").Include("~/Styles/bootstrap.css", "~/Styles/site.css"))
  End Sub
End Module
```

Here's my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
  @Styles.Render("~/content/css")

</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", New With {.area = ""}, New With {.class = "navbar-brand"})
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
        @*@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")*@
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
  </div>

  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
  @RenderSection("scripts", required:=False)
</body>
</html>
```

(I've commented out the `_LoginPartial` dependency, as I don't need that part right now.)

Here's my view:

```
@Code
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
End Code

@Code
  ViewBag.Title = "Index"
End Code

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>Hello from our View Template!</p>
```

...and here's the rendered HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Styles/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
      <h2>Index</h2>
      <p>Hello from our View Template!</p>
      <hr />
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2020 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

All of the page's resources are loading correctly:

[image]

I went through all the CSS classes in my layout file and verified that they all exist in both `boostrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`.

It appears the Bootstrap styles aren't being applied for some reason, but I'm not 100% sure of this.

I'm at a loss. What's going wrong here? How can I begin to track this down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but when I closed the browser tab and reloaded the page in a new tab, everything rendered as expected.